# Dagger-2: How to create different instantiations for the same object type depending on their scope?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a component-subcomponent relationship. Each have a different scope and use their own module which supplies a depedency of the same type. What I need is different object instantations based on the scope. Dagger won't allow that since I will have "multiple bindings". How would I solve the problem without @Named-Qualifiers? For example, is there a way to overwrite in the subcomponent?

```
//Higher scoped object (in component)

    @Provides
    @ClientScope
    ISupResRankStrategy iSupResRankStrategy(@Named("GlobalModelConfig") JsonNode configSubTree,
            Lazy<SortByMagnitudeSum> strat1,
            Lazy<SortByShadowPercentage> strat2) {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map<String, Lazy> availableStrategies = new HashMap<>();
        availableStrategies.put(SortByMagnitudeSum.class.getSimpleName(), strat1);
        availableStrategies.put(SortByShadowPercentage.class.getSimpleName(), strat2);

        String configuredStrategy = configSubTree.findValue("ISupResRankStrategy").asText();
        return (ISupResRankStrategy) availableStrategies.get(configuredStrategy).get();
    }
```

```
//lower scoped object (in subcomponent)
@Provides
@ModelScope
ISupResRankStrategy iSupResRankStrategy(@Named("TradeModelConfig") JsonNode configSubTree,
        Lazy<SortByMagnitudeSum> strat1,
        Lazy<SortByShadowPercentage> strat2) {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map<String, Lazy> availableStrategies = new HashMap<>();
    availableStrategies.put(SortByMagnitudeSum.class.getSimpleName(), strat1);
    availableStrategies.put(SortByShadowPercentage.class.getSimpleName(), strat2);

    String configuredStrategy = configSubTree.findValue("ISupResRankStrategy").asText();
    return (ISupResRankStrategy) availableStrategies.get(configuredStrategy).get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dagger won't allow that since I will have "multiple bindings". How would I solve the problem without @Named-Qualifiers? For example, is there a way to overwrite in the subcomponent?

There isn't. You can't have 2 objects of the same type available with different scopes at the same time. How should Dagger know which of the 2 you want?

To have multiple objects of the same kind you can

- use `@Qualifier`, `@Named` is one of them, but you can create your own with better names, e.g. `@Client`, `@Model`
- use component dependencies instead of Subcomponents, this way you can not expose the object to the dependent components, allowing for their own instance

Comment: Thanks for the qualifiers alternative as well. Didn't like the idea of using strings around my code from the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

use @Qualifier, @Named. you can overload DI

for eg

```
 @Provides @Named("type1") 
  Model provideModel() {
  return new Model();
  }

 @Provides @Named("type2") 
 Model provideModeWithContext(Context context) {
 return new Model(context);
   }
```